# MyFunction() Uncaught Reference error

Tags: javascript

Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

This is my .js file which isn't working or calling on my HTML

```
function = myFunction() 
{
    var ret = "";
    for (var i = 15; i < 26; i++) 
    {
        ret += i + "  " + i*2 + "  " + i*3 + "\n";    
    }
    alert(ret);
}
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Test1.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<h1> Exercise 4 - LAB 4  </h1>

<h2> Exercise 2.1 </h2>

<button type="button" onclick= "myFunction() "> Press Me </button>

</body>
</html>
```

Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

Comment: Remove the `=` in `function = myFunction()`. Should be `function myFunction() {...}` _or_ `myFunction = function() {...}`

Answer (score 5):

Here you go:

```
var myFunction = function ()
{
    var ret = "";
    for (var i = 15; i < 26; i++)
    {
        ret += i + "  " + i*2 + "  " + i*3 + "\n";
    }
    alert(ret);
};
```

`function = varName () {}` is a syntax error. You can do it like this: `function varName () {}` without the equals sign, or you can do it the way I did it.

After a little bit of healthy admonishment from some of our fellow posters, I should point out that there is a difference between these two ways to write a function. To quote RobG: "There is no practical difference between function foo(){} and var foo = function(){}; other than when the function is created and that the first is called a FunctionDeclaration and the second a FunctionExpression." A function declaration is loaded before any code is executed, so you can can call it anywhere (before or after the function's location in the file). However, again in terms of actual location in the file, if you call a function expression before its location in the file, an error will be thrown. (You can however get around this by declaring the variable that will later be assigned to the function expression at the beginning of the file.)

Comment: Please always tell the OP _what you changed_ and why.

Comment: I think you are confused about execution contexts and declarations. There is no practical difference between `function foo(){}` and `var foo = function(){};` other than *when* the function is created and that the first is called a *FunctionDeclaration* and the second a *FunctionExpression*. Both are "bound" to their current execution context (global, function or eval).

Comment: You are right it is bound to the current context. Darn it. The only time i have used a function declaration in a long time is for naming callbacks that are declared at the same time they are passed as an argument. I was definitely wrong. I made edits. I will have to look up the difference between a function declaration and function expression right now.

Comment: Wow I thought the generally accepted 'best practice' was to always use function expressions. Yet, that always causes difficulties like having to declare all kinds of variables at the beginning of the file that will later be used to name functions. Now I see the difference -- function declarations are loaded before any code is executed. Thank you very much RobG.

Answer (score 2):

```
function = myFunction() { /* body */ }
```

is invalid syntax. Didn't you get an error in the console from this? The correct syntax is either

```
function myFunction() { /* body */ }
```

or

```
myFunction = function() { /* body */ }
```

You can also write:

```
somename = function myFunction()  { /* body */ };
```

However, in this case the scope of the name `myFunction` is just the body, it's not global.

Comment: Ahh, I was thinking of `function = function myFunction() {...}`

Comment: Still invalid.  Probably `var fn = function myFunction() {...}`

Comment: @Dennis Because `function` is a reserved word, so can't be the name of a function?

Comment: @Barmar—your last explanation isn't quite right: IE creates an identifier for named function expressions (which is one good reason not to use them) in their outer scope, not just within the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of the function is wrong:
Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
    var ret = "";
    for (var i=15; i<26; i++) {
        ret += i + "  " + (i*2) + "  " + (i*3) + "\n";    
    }
    alert(ret);
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Test1.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Exercise 4 - LAB 4</h1>
    <h2>Exercise 2.1</h2>
    <input type="button" value="Press Me" onclick="myFunction()" />
  </body>
</html>
```